# Drupal 7/PayPal Express Checkout: How to set delivery options based on address

Tags: paypal, drupal-7, drupal-commerce

I have the "PayPal Express Checkout" Drupal 7 module installed and I need to ideally register what country the customer is checking out from and charge them a standard shipping fee, for example:

UK: £4.50
EU: £12
USA: £20
Australia: £20

If this isn't possible then alternatively offer the following as delivery charges:
UK: £4.50
EU: £12
Rest of the World: £20

Currently only one delivery option is displayed and this seems to be displayed with an "After adding a product to the cart" event.  Adding other events wouldn't display delivery option choices, but would list and total them as far as I understand it.

I'm not sure how best to proceed with this, can anyone offer any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

1 – Clone the “Paypal Express Checkout” rule for each shipping option

2 – Edit the condition in the newly cloned rule and set the country code based on what the rule should use.

3 – Edit the shipping service action to use the relevant shipping option.